# Obtaining a font outside of a package

Tags: fonts

How can I obtain the "Galliard" font? I have been searching around for the font and I haven't been able to find a way to get it for LaTeX. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Galliard isn't a free typeface. If you own it, you can easily use it with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Is there a free version similar to it?

Comment: [accanthis](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/accanthis) lists Galliard as one of the fonts it can replace.

Comment: For others' reference, it looks quite different. But thanks for the citation.

Comment: Accanthis is a nice typeface, but doesn't seem to me to be alike Galliard. The lower-case, italic 'g' in Galliard is unique. (See here for a comparison: https://ibin.co/36zCLEXMEkyO.png) However, Accanthis includes a bold-italic font, which ITC Galliard lacks, and that is plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand upon the comment given by NVaughan:

If you use LuaTeX (or XeTeX) you can access any TrueType or Open Type font, without the need of a TeX package. In fact, having a TeX package is often a nuisance.

For example, if you have the license for non-free ITC Galliard Pro, you could do this:

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % So that `` becomes “ etc.
\RequirePackage{polyglossia} % not babel
\setmainfont{ITC Galliard Pro} % If you have the license.
\begin{document}
This text is in ITC Galliard Pro.
\end{document}
```

See how easy that is? In fact, the font can be installed in a variety of places accessible to LuaTeX, not just in your TeX tree. If you have used LuaTeX before and add a new font, you'll need to re-build the luatex-cache. Easiest way to do that it to find where it is, and discard the old cache.

Since you will be working with modern fonts and utf-8 encoding, you can directly insert characters in any language that the font supports. None of that "OT1" or "T1" stuff.

Comment: Wow... How easy is it to transition from LuaLaTeX and what is the backwards compatibility like?

Comment: The only significant learning curve was reading the `fontspec` manual. Easy to do if you already know how Open Type fonts work. You don't need to know it all. But once you see how powerful it is, you'll wonder why you never did it before. You won't go back! You do not need to know Lua code. That's all "under the hood" unless you want to unleash its full power as a programming language (I have never done that). Other than specifying fonts, just about all the rest of the LaTeX code is the same. I hear that some packages are incompatible, but none that I have used.

Comment: +1. A note: The `fontspec` option `Ligatures=TeX` has been the default for several years by now. No need to specify this option unless one has a rather out-of-date TeX distribution.